# How to create a SharePoint List to use as a private gallery in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sharepoint-2010, visual-studio-extensions

I would like to add a [private extension gallery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh266746.aspx) to my Visual Studio installation and provide the extensions listed there by means of a SharePoint-list. MSDN has an [article about that topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh266718.aspx), however that doesn't help much.

I tried to create a simple document list - that won't work however.

Any ideas on how to proceed here?

Comment: According to [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsx/thread/28551672-eefb-4d64-9597-2774ad9b7151) in the MSDN forums there is currently no official support for that feature on the server side of life...

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to find out the same thing, the MSDN information isn't clear (as usual). I.e Do I *have* to configure a `Sharepoint` server just to host an `xml` file and a `vsix` file???

I have found this [article](http://msmvps.com/blogs/p3net/archive/2013/01/11/hosting-a-private-visual-studio-gallery.aspx) which gives details on how to setup a gallery with `IIS`, which sounds a lot more straightforward than the `MSDN` explanation.

Will post anything else I find.

**Edit**: The article also includes a link to an [extension](http://inmetavsgallery.codeplex.com/) that helps setup your gallery, tutorial [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/jakob/archive/2012/11/07/using-private-extension-galleries-in-visual-studio-2012.aspx).

Comment: Looks promising - will have a detailed look at that when I am back from vacation...

Comment: I've used this extension in the past. I believe it's no longer supported in the latest versions of VS. Also, the links are dead. Seems to me the only viable solution is creating an Atom feed. I just found out there is a VsixUtil that could be useful in creating the feed (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/how-to-create-vsix-feed-for-private-gallery?view=vs-2019).